# Get file params (size, filename) in django rest framewrok

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to **get file params** in my rest api.

**Model:**

```py
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='files/courses/', default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Serializer:**

```py
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attachment = serializers.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title','attachment')
```

**View:**

```py
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
```

When I do GET request, I get the title, and file url,
But I wnat to get also file size, and file name.
How to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the simple solutions is overriding the **`to_representation()`** method of the **`MovieSerializer`** class as,

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attachment = serializers.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'attachment')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        attachment = {
            "url": representation.pop("attachment"),
            "size": instance.attachment.size,
            "name": instance.attachment.name,
        }
        representation['attachment'] = attachment
        return representation
```

Comment: This is throwing a FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/project/media/styles/graded.svg'. Can you think of a solution?